# Exiting out of sub if result of query to database is DbNull

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ms-access

I have an edit profile page where the user can edit their profile information. At the minute, new users cannot use this page as they have not got a corresponding record in the 'userprofiles' table. I am using the aspnet_ membership system with corresponding aspnet_User tables in the same database. There is no link between 'userprofiles' and the aspnet tables

I have a sub called 'DisplayData()' that checks if there is a record for the user in the table and displays their profile information in the textboxes. Unfortunately, for new users, there is no record in the table so it throws an error

Here is my Page_Load sub:

```
   Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Session("userName") = User.Identity.Name
        Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
        conn.Open()
        Dim cmdcheck As New OleDbCommand("SELECT TravellerName FROM userprofiles WHERE (TravellerName = ?) ", conn)
        cmdcheck.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userName", Session("userName"))
        Dim profileCheckDr = cmdcheck.ExecuteReader()
        If IsDBNull(profileCheckDr("TravellerName")) Then
            ??
        End If
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            DisplayData()
            savec.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub
```

And here is my DisplayData() function which inputs all current user profile information into the textboxes on the page:

```
Protected Sub DisplayData()
        Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("BookMeetConnString").ConnectionString)
        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM userprofiles WHERE TravellerName=@f1"
        Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, conn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f1", User.Identity.Name)
        conn.Open()
        Dim profileDr = cmd.ExecuteReader()
        profileDr.Read()
        Dim newEmailAddress = ""
        Dim newDescription = ""
        Dim newDOB = ""
        Dim newLocation = ""
        Dim newProfession = ""
        Dim newSmoker = ""
        Dim newDrinker = ""
        Dim newEducationLevel = ""
        Dim newMaritalStatus = ""
        If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("AvatarURL")) Then ProfilePic.ImageUrl = profileDr.Item("AvatarURL")
        If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("EmailAddress")) Then newEmailAddress = profileDr.Item("EmailAddress")
        If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("DOB")) Then newDOB = profileDr.Item("DOB")
        If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("Location")) Then newLocation = profileDr.Item("Location")
        If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("Description")) Then newDescription = profileDr.Item("Description")
        If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("Profession")) Then newProfession = profileDr.Item("Profession")
        If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("Smoker")) Then newSmoker = profileDr.Item("Smoker")
        If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("Drinker")) Then newDrinker = profileDr.Item("Drinker")
        If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("EducationLevel")) Then newEducationLevel = profileDr.Item("EducationLevel")
        If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("MaritalStatus")) Then newMaritalStatus = profileDr.Item("MaritalStatus")
        If Not IsDBNull(profileDr("AvatarURL")) Then ProfilePic.ImageUrl = profileDr.Item("AvatarURL")
        description.Text = newDescription
        email.Text = newEmailAddress
        smoker.SelectedValue = newSmoker
        drinker.SelectedValue = newDrinker
        dd_userlocation.SelectedValue = newLocation
        dob.Text = newDOB
        educationlevel.SelectedValue = newEducationLevel
        profession.SelectedValue = newProfession
        maritalstatus.SelectedValue = newMaritalStatus

        conn.Close()

    End Sub
```

How do I break out of the Page Load sub so that the DisplayData() sub doesn't run if the results of the query in the Page Load sub do not return anything. I've already tried using 'Exit Sub' but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Wrap the call to `DisplayData` in the if block - like this:  `If Not IsDBNull(profileCheckDr("TravellerName")) Then DisplayData() End If`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to simply move your If statement to surround the call to `DisplayData`:

```
If Not IsPostback Then
    If Not IsDBNull(profileCheckDr("TravellerName")) Then
        DisplayData()
    End If
End If
```

However, the real question is - **if the user has not registered for your site yet, how are they even able to get to the Edit Profile page?**  Unregistered users should not be able to get to user-specific parts of your site.